# How to read data from text file in Workbench/VxWorks project

Tags: c, workbench, vxworks, file-read

I have a C program which reads data from a text file (using fopen and fscanf ) and proceses it. I'm trying to implement that in VxWorks/Workbench as a RTP project in simulator mode. But it shows an error at fscanf. Is it possible at all to execute this operation in VxWorks. I am new to Worbench/VxWorks.

Comment: Can you give the error response of fscanf?

Comment: The process terminates with segsegv error (segmentation fault). The error is same if i use fread with binary file. I checked the address returned by fopen is 000000. This may be causing sigsegv error while using fread or fscanf. Though i don't know why this is happening. I have copied the file i'm reading in the project folder.